Bitbucket Pipeline => Build Fail
Error i am getting:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project *****: There are test failures.

Yml file:

POM.xml:

Error

at local running fine but at bitbucket pipeline getting issue. where is the gap?

Do not post images... also the test is timed out... also asking why using such an old Maven version and surefire plugin version etc... ?

WebDriver Timed out ... - Maybe the build does not work in the headless environment you run it, not providing a display/screen where a web browser can run the tests via the WebDriver.
